# Where is Android Support package in the Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android

I am using Intellij Idea (same thing as Android Studio). Today I decided to update packages in Android SDK Manager, and during the update, my computer crashed. When I rebooted Ubuntu, the android executable was missing. So I re-extracted the android-sdk and got it working again. However, some jar files are missing, as shown in the attachment.[image]

Apparently, when I installed all the necessary packages in the SDK Manager, I missed a package pertaining to android-support-v4.jar. I googled and found [this](https://www.in-nomine.org/2012/02/26/adding-android-support-v4-to-your-android-application-in-intellij-idea/) link. It says download  Android Support package under Extras. But I do not see it. I just see something called Android Support repository.[image] Is it the same thing? If not, where can I get the Android Support package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Support Repository is the only entry still being updated and is all you need to run a Gradle based builds.

The now obsolete 'Android Support Library' package can be found by checking the 'Obsolete' checkbox in the bottom left and allows you to use at latest version 23.2.1.

Comment: Even when I check "Obsolete" it is not there. Has it been removed now from the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: @voxoid - I don't see it anymore.