# How to use Gluon with recent Android SDK?

Tags: android, gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to evaluate Gluon but I'm having trouble compiling the examples.

In the prerequisites it requires the Android SDK module 'Android Support Library' but this is not packaged with the Android SDK for Linux anymore. I've tried both the stand-alone SDK as well as Android Studio, but they behave exactly the same.

What I tried is specifying `androidSdk = '/home/mark/Progs/android-sdk-linux'` in build.gradle, which makes it successfully find the SDK.

The real problem is the following:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'mergeClassesIntoJar' during up-to-date check.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mark/Progs/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar (No such file or directory)
```

I've tried all the forum and StackOverflow posts I could find, and mostly they tell that I have to check 'Show Obsolete' in the SDK Manager to find 'Android Support Library', but it's just not there anymore.

[image: Screenshot of the SDK Manager with 'Obsolete' checked]

---

Also tried:

- `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` (and 1.0.1)
- `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'` (and 21.0.3)
- `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0"`
   (these just give more errors early on in the compile process)
- Searching for '*multidex*.jar'; nothing found

Is Gluon just not compatible anymore with the Android SDK anno December 2016?

Comment: See the comments for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133317/javafxports-android-gradle-task-requires-android-support-library-which-is-re)

Comment: Solution here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133317/javafxports-android-gradle-task-requires-android-support-library-which-is-re

Answer (score 0):

IT is compatible and I ran it on both Android and IOS devices.

for Android you need to set the bath of the android ask in your Project > BuiltScripts> build.gradle

```
jfxmobile {
downConfig {
    version = '3.0.0'
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
}
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    compileSdkVersion=25
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.0'
    androidSdk='/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk'
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonapplication.**.*',
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]

}
```

}