# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidRuntimeNoRetrolambdaCopy'. Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

Tags: android, mobile, javafx, gluon

After Run /gradle Android to deploy the Gluon app in my Android Phone. I have this error:

```
org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetColumn$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields$$Lambda$1
:mergeClassesIntoJar
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'mergeClassesIntoJar' during up-to-date check.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/yotti/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

After update the JFXPlugin like in the Image ,i have this error

A problem occurred configuring root project 'SingleViewProject'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidRuntimeNoRetrolambdaCopy'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
>        Required by:
>            :SingleViewProject:unspecified

[image]

Comment: check if you have antivirus enabled and it delete the dex file that will cause of problem.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133317/javafxports-android-gradle-task-requires-android-support-library-which-is-re). Probably you will just need to update your `jfxplugin` version to 1.3.1, then clean, reload the project and build again.

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya. I use Mac. I don't have Antivirus

Comment: @JoséPereda i have Install the Plugin in Eclipse IDE. I use Gluon on Eclipse

Comment: As I said, update the jfxplugin version on your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @JoséPereda i have update it. When i clean the Project i have this error * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SingleViewProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidRuntimeNoRetrolambdaCopy'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:

Comment: Edit your question, post your `build.gradle` file, and also refer to this new error, otherwise is impossible to know what could be happening.

Comment: @JoséPereda buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}

Comment: @JoséPereda I have only 6 Reputation. I can not edit the Question

Comment: @JoséPereda i Update the Post and put a Image of my grade.build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was already mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133317/javafxports-android-gradle-task-requires-android-support-library-which-is-re), Android obsolete library `Android Support Library` is no longer available.

Using `jfxmobile` plugin version 1.3.1 solves the issue, as it uses the multidex library that should be found here: `ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.aar`.

Note you need to install with the Android SDK Manager both Extras/Google Repository and Extras/Android Support Repository.

Also is advisable to create a properties file with the ANDROID_HOME variable, under `/Users/<user>/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/yotti/Library/Android/sdk
```

and remove the line in the build.gradle -> jfxmobile -> android -> androidSdk.

As for the Charm dependencies you are using the wrong repository, you need:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}
```

Finally, you don't show a ControlsFX dependency, so it is not possible to have the exception posted in the first place.