# Gluon: Multidex - Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidRuntimeNoRetrolambdaCopy'

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon

When compiling my JavaFX project for Android in Netbeans I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project ''.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidRuntimeNoRetrolambdaCopy'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
         http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
         http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         ::unspecified
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.1.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
androidSdk = 'C:/Users/mitch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

What I have tried:
- Using a different version for jfxmobile (I used to have 1.2.0 which resulted in a successful build but when compiling for android results in:)

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'mergeClassesIntoJar' during up-to-date check.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\multidex\library\libs\android-support-multidex.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

- Use a different charm version
- Google: 
  Which only results in ONE exact same thread that doesn't help: [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidRuntimeNoRetrolambdaCopy'. Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428142/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-androidruntimenoretrolamb)
- Installed the Google Support and Android Support in SDK manager
- When I navigate to the repository file, it does not exist.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: If you have installed Google Repository and Android Support repository, you should be able to find `ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.aar`. Until you don't get this fixed you won't be able to solve the issue.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes this file does indeed exist! I stumbled on it earlier but since it is not a .jar I thought it would be useless. Can you tell me what to do now that I have located the file?

Comment: Ask the answer you mentioned already says, create a gradle.properties file with the ANDROID_HOME path

Comment: @JoséPereda I already have the SDK defined as such: androidSdk = 'C:/Users/mitch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk' - Do i need to change this, the file is already in there

Comment: As I said, remove that from the build file and create the property file with it.

Comment: @JoséPereda EDIT: I aplogize for being stupid, it worked, thank you so mutch! Hopefully this helps others as well

Comment: Root directory? You need to place it in your user home folder `C:/Users/Mitch/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Comment: @JoséPereda I placed it in my app root directory, but the APK was created. Should I still move the properties file?

Comment: If you place it on your gradle home folder, you won't need to do it again for other projects

Comment: @JoséPereda many thanks!