# Issue to build Gluon Application on Mac os Sierra for Android Gradle Build

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, gluon

I am unable to install Android support Library,

I am using Macos Sierra ,
Eclipse Neon,
Gluon Plugin with Android-Sdk
Build.gradle is :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
repositories {
jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'
jfxmobile {
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    androidSdk = '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/'
}
}
```

the Exception is when i run AndroidInstall On Adb device  :

> Cannot expand ZIP
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar'
>   as it does not exist.

---

SDK-MANAGER LOOKS LIKE :
[i cannot see the Android support Library even if i check obsolete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcUv9.png)

i have did this also :

```
android update sdk --no-ui -a --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```

please Help

Comment: This is a duplicated question. See this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143300/how-can-i-install-android-support-library-to-deploy-a-gluon-mobile-application/42143741#42143741)