# Gluon Applicatiopn Error Android Support Packages

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gluon

I have a problem with Gluon on Intellij I installed all teh Packages at the Android SDK Manager. And linked the android SDK Path in my Gluon Project build.gradle.

But i throws this Error all the times:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
You must install the Android Support Repository. Open the Android SDK Manager and choose the Android Support Repository from the Extras category at the bottom of the list of packages.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.386 secs
You must install the Android Support Repository. Open the Android SDK Manager and choose the Android Support Repository from the Extras category at the bottom of the list of packages.
18:06:45: External task execution finished 'androidInstall'.
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'me.gentlexd.gluon.Main'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.1'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:4.3.1'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:4.3.1'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:4.3.1'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.2.4'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = "F:/Android"
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143300/how-can-i-install-android-support-library-to-deploy-a-gluon-mobile-application/42143741#42143741)

Answer (score 0):

You must create (but if not exists) gradle.properties in Users//.gradle/gradle.properties and add ANDROID_HOME=PathToAndroidSDK
This is my ANDROID_HOME=U:/AndroidStudio.