# Gluon You must install the android support repository Error

Tags: android, gluon-mobile

Below are my build.gradle and my stack trace for the problem. I've installed the google and android support repository's through the SDK and I'm still getting this error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    Issue 1
--------

  Requested project: F:\NoPanicsSelfHelper

  Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.runBuild(AsyncGradleTask.java:368)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgressIgnoreTaskDefCancel(AsyncGradleTask.java:491)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgressIgnoreTaskDefCancel(AsyncGradleTask.java:401)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgress(AsyncGradleTask.java:392)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.access$400(AsyncGradleTask.java:93)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask$BuildExecutionItem$1.run(AsyncGradleTask.java:775)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:51)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$200(GradleDaemonManager.java:22)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:128)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$QueuedItem.runTask(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1213)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker.executeTask(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1049)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker.run(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1179)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker$1.run(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:998)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: You must install the Android Support Repository. Open the Android SDK Manager and choose the Android Support Repository from the Extras category at the bottom of the list of packages.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: You must install the Android Support Repository. Open the Android SDK Manager and choose the Android Support Repository from the Extras category at the bottom of the list of packages.
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin$_apply_closure7.doCall(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy:279)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.graphPopulated(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        ... 32 more
```

---

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.5'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }

}

mainClassName = 'com.nopanicsselfhelper.NoPanicsSelfHelper'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.2'

}

jfxmobile {

    downConfig {

        version = '3.2.4'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }

    android {

        applicationPackage = 'com.nopanicsselfhelper.NoPanicsSelfHelper.java'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        resDirectory = 'src/android/res'
    dependencies {

    }
}
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: android skd extras screenshot]

Comment: `You must install the Android Support Repository. Open the Android SDK Manager and choose the Android Support Repository from the Extras category at the bottom of the list of packages.` Show us a screenshot proving that you have done this :-)

Comment: Follow the steps from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42143741/3956070). Make sure you remove the `androidSdk` from the build gradle, and you create a `gradle.properties` file with `ANDROID_HOME` instead.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. gradle.properties is already configured with android_home.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, remove `androidSdk` from the build.gradle file. And you don't need `multidex-1.0.1` as a dependency either.

Comment: Thank you for commenting again. I've done both of those and still no luck. I've edited the original question with the changes I made to the build.gradle file.

Comment: Can you double check the gradle.properties file contains the correct path for Android SDK, and it is placed under your <user>/.gradle folder?

Comment: Thank you, I have double checked and corrected an error it is now working. Thank José.

Comment: @MarkRees What did you change? Can you share please? This is  my gradle.properties: `C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143300/how-can-i-install-android-support-library-to-deploy-a-gluon-mobile-application/42143741#42143741), gradle.properties need to be located in .gradle.

However, after running with --debug option, I found that gradle looks for gradle.properties in the current directory where you run gradle command (in my case, it is the root directory of project).

So you need to put gradle.properties in it.