# Gluon javafx with netbeans error android install

Tags: gluon-mobile

Error while trying to to do android install
  Execution failed for task ':mergeClassesIntoJar'.

> Cannot expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Path..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\multidex\library\libs\android-support-multidex.jar' as it does not exist.

```
Can any one pleas help am fed up of this issue no proper solution below is my code 
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.netbeansdemo.NetbeansDemo'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:3.0.0'

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/ee209275/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'io.datafx.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your dependencies are quite outdated. The jfxmobile plugin version is now 1.3.6. You should update the Gluon plugin for your IDE and create a new project to see the new build file. As for the error, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143741/3956070).

Comment: yes i tried with new on only with classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9' , but still its same .. that why i come across one post and changed it and tried . Can you please help me on this.. its taking lot time for me to resolve .

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Gluon plugin for your IDE, so you can generate a project with updated dependencies. Current versions of the plugin are 2.5.0 for NetBeans and IntelliJ, 2.4.0 for Eclipse.

For a single view project, this will be the `build.gradle` file you will get:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonhq.testplugin.GluonTestPlugin'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.5'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.3.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

You have an issue with the Android SDK path. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143741/3956070) shows how to solve it.

Basically:

- Open the Android SDK Manager and make sure you have installed Extras/Google Repository and Extras/Android Support Repository.
- Remove the `androidSdk` line from the android block on your build.gradle file and move it to a properties file. For that, just create a properties file under `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\gradle.properties`, and add the `ANDROID_HOME` variable: `ANDROID_HOME=C:/<path.to.Android>/sdk`.

Then reload your project, see that it works on desktop, and then deploy to mobile.