# Gluon mobile , issues

Tags: gluon

what so ever i tried, i traced all the the topics available on the net, even after a clean Windows build, and following step by step the instructions on gluon mobile docs, i cant make the plugin work. 
every time netbeans complaning abaout not able to fire javafxports.jfxmobile plugin. and my stacktrace is like below. 
Please help.

---

gradle file is;

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.b.B'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.7'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.6.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}​
```

---

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Gradle\gradle-2.2'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
at org.netbeans.gradle.model.GenericModelFetcher.getModels(GenericModelFetcher.java:168)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader$ProjectModelFetcher.getModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:375)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader.loadModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:68)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.loadModelWithProgress(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:586)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.fixProjectLoadKey(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:385)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.access$1500(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:74)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader$7.run(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:441)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runNonBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:35)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$100(GradleDaemonManager.java:22)
at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:125)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.runTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:919)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.access$1200(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:898)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.executeTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:815)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.processQueue(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:827)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:861)
at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$1.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:453)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\Users\tolga\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\build.gradle' line: 10
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:31)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
... 32 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException:    Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile']
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:117)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:131)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at build_10pni916juwlkn0xu47o88is8.run(C:\Users\tolga\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\build.gradle:10)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
... 43 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'iosClasses' on task set.
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin.createIosTasks(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy:582)
at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin.apply(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy:160)
at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin.apply(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:188)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:137)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:115)
... 52 more
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file, and what tasks are you trying to run (desktop or mobile or both).

Comment: both. and my gradle file is

Comment: this should be fine i beleive.

Comment: NetBeans has an option to run the gradle wrapper (Options->Miscellaneous->Gradle, select use Wrapper). Then launch the Build task again. Also you can try from command line, under the root of the project, execute: `gradlew clean build run` and see if it works.

Comment: i tried everything. all the gradle combinations in net beans + gradle versions 2.2 to 4.1. as well as cmd . cant manage to run dalvik example files as well. i modified gradle file and insert the line where android sdk is(even though i have a ANDROID_HOME variable.).  version numbers etc, as it is said in the other post answered here. İ have a proper GRADLE_HOME,JAVA_HOME env variable. cmd and netbeans always complains the same thing. it is not  be able to fire up jfxmobile plugin

Comment: and i am realy stuck. and my curiosity is realy at the top on 'what do i do wrong?'. by the way is gluon plugin  chosing android sdk version?should we install some erlier versions?

Comment: If you have followed carefully the steps [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.3.7/#_prerequisites) you should have installed Android sdk (at least platform 21, Build tools, at least 23.0.1), and set the ANDROID_HOME in the `C:/Users/<user>/.gradle/gradle.properties` file. Try to run at least this on command line and post the result: `gradlew --info clean build`.

Comment: This might help: your project location is named `test`, but your project name is `B`? I created a project with the Gluon plugin, named `B`, package `com.b`, main class `B`, and its location is `/NetBeansProjects/B` as well. Just make sure the project is located at the same location as the name you gave it.

Comment: Jose thank you but still i am at the same place. the error as always(from cmd)
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile']
   > Could not get unknown property 'iosClasses' for task set.

Comment: but strangely there is no gradle.properties file in C:/Users/<user>/.gradle/.  There was though, before i reinstal Windows yesterday. because i did this trick you suggested.

Comment: i am missing something very very simple but what?

Comment: Make sure you have that file there with ANDROID_HOME and the right Android sdk path. Then create _another_ project on NetBeans (just select Gluon->Single View, and accept everything as is by default), and click run. It should work.

Comment: yep i put a gradle.properties file there with ANDROID_HOME = 'C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk' i still get the same error.

Comment: both on CMD and netbeans

Comment: remove the quote marks, just `ANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk`

Comment: like a joke.....but no way.

Comment: One last thought: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143741/3956070), you may have the issue related at the end: you have Android installed in a folder without enough permissions. Can you try to move it to a different one?

Comment: José ,I cant make it work. I completely install Android in my documents, where I have full privileges.(change the env variable path as well). still I have a warning about jfxmobile plugin I changed the version 1.3.2 on gradle build but no luck its just downloading but giving the same error. I found a jar file of this plugin from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javafxports/jfxmobile-plugin/1.3.2 but I have no idea where to put or what to do with this jar file.

Comment: my suspect is there must be something wrong with the android. I don't use the one come  with androidstudio.(at the moment no android studio available on my pc) I found an executable one. install what it suggests to me +  SDK build tolls 23.0.2+android support repository and  google repository . İ am writing these because it sucks with mobile. plugin works fine with gluon desktop projects. it seems somehow gradle and android cant cominicate. but I have no bullet left. İ believe i've done everything you suggested. and this shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: I really appreciate of your help. thank you man.

Comment: Make sure your custom Android install is correct. For that, you can download android tools for Windows [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip), unzip it, and then install a platform and the tools running on command line: `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25"`. Update the path to this sdk, and you should be able to run the plugin for android tasks.

Comment: ok did it but how can I execute this ----> running on command line: sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25"

Comment: The sdkmanager is a batch file inside `sdk/tools/bin`

Comment: José, sorry for the delay, as always I have the same result. 'Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile']'. Although I extracted the new sdk to another folder with full privilages, and with proper paths set. I really don't understand.