# Cannot install sdkmanager in windows 10

Tags: android, batch-file, sdk

I am trying to install the sdk manager alone for using it with Eclipse. I downloaded the zip file provided by google -

commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip

from https://developer.android.com/studio

But as I try to run the sdkmanager.bat file it doesn't run and i am getting the following errors:

```
Error: could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
```

Please note that Java jdk path is set properly and there is no error with respect to that.

If you are interested to look at the bat file, here it is:

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  sdkmanager startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\..

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
@rem set JAVA_EXE=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java.exe
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\/sdkmanager-classpath.jar

@rem Execute sdkmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

- copy the content of `tools/lib/_` to `tools/lib`
- run `sdkmanager` commands with `--sdk_root` parameter.

#### Details

In the line 66 of the sdkmanager.bat, CLASSPATH is defined to be like this

```
set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\/sdkmanager-classpath.jar
```

and inside the lib directory, `sdkmanager-classpath.jar` is, oddly, under a subdirectory called `-`.

I tried to change the path in the batch file but it did not work, so I copied the files from `..../tools/lib/_` to `..../tools/lib` and the error disappeard. However, a warning appeared:

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60454207/5107788) answer, I tried to pass the `--sdk_root` parameter which worked without problems:

```
sdkmanager --sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME% --list
# %ANDROID_HOME% is the environment variable that contains the path of android
# sdk installation. Typically, would be:
# `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools`
```

> PS: even I was able to solve this, I would say that this answer is a workaround since the documentation does not mention anything about copying files to other path

Comment: Really strange why we need to do this - and especially that we are suppose to know without anyone telling us...!

Comment: I think this is an error in the packaging of the windows command-line tools. The Mac version as them in the correct directory. Also, the entries in the MANIFEST.MF inside the sdkmanager-classpath.jar are all relative to tools\lib (so the jar should be in that directory as well).

Comment: See the issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152329644

Comment: And what happens if I'm running Flutter?. How do I execute the command flutter doctor --android-licenses?

Answer (score 0):

I post this for my short note upon the solution.
After done several research only specify sdk_root parameter solve Java problem.

```
sdkmanager --sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME% --install [Package_name]
```

Where %ANDROID_HOME% specify a PATH to android SDK extracted. e.g. "d:\android-sdk"
Package_name can be obtained from --list option.

```
sdkmanager --sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME% --list
```

I use this for Appium so only platform-tools, platforms [API Level] Should be fine. Emulator if you want to use AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and did not get any solution and one day by mistake I got the solution.

At first I kept the SDK folder wherever I wanted but this gave the error, so I kept it in the AppData folder (in Windows) 
`C:/Users/{username}/AppData`

This folder is hidden by default, so either search for it in the address bar or enable to show the hidden folder and keep the SDK folder there